# Существует ли специализированное аппаратное обеспечение для C# приложений?

Tags: c#

Я работаю над одним приложением, которое распознает образы с помощью веб-камеры и подает сигналы на другие платы, однако для запуска этого приложения мне нужно постоянно носить с собой ноутбук, где я запускаю это приложение, но у меня есть большое желание создать что то более "композитное". Я бы хотел иметь что то, куда я бы мог закинуть свое приложение и просто нажать кнопку "включить" и далее этот "композитный компьютер" исполнял бы мое приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, .NET Core на Raspberry Pi.

[Гайд 1](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md) | [Гайл 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david/2017/07/20/setting_up_raspian_and_dotnet_core_2_0_on_a_raspberry_pi/)

Comment: Малина, наверно, единственное что приходит на ум, да. Я бы добавил ещё про какой-нибудь завалявшийся андроидфон+xamarin, но с этой связкой все сложнее...

Comment: @SimonBarkovsky если вам ответ помог - отметьте его как правильный.